# Populate inner html code after dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, innerhtml

I have a select:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Oyunçu seçin</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <?php $players = select("`id`,`name`","`players`","`id`","ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>
                                <select id="player" name="player" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="0">--Oyunçu seçin--</option>
                                <?
                                foreach ($players as $player) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$player['id'].'">'.$player['name'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                                <div id="divFileInput"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Once item selected in this selection the new texboxes appear:

```
   $(function(){
        $('#player').change(function(){
            var selections = $("#player :selected");
            var html = '';
            $.each(selections,function(i,item){
                html += ':<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2">Ad</label>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control"  value="<?= $playerfetch['name'];?>" readonly>' +
                    '</div></div><div class="form-group">' +
                    '<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Kod</label>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" readonly>' +
                    '</div></div>'+
                '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2">Doğum tarixi</label>' +
                  '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="birthday" name="birthday" class="form-control" readonly>' +
                    '</div></div><div class="form-group">' +
                    '<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Cins</label>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" readonly>' +
                    '</div></div>' +
                '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2">Məşqçi</label>' +
                '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                '<input type="text" id="trainer" name="trainer" class="form-control" readonly>' +
                '</div></div><div class="form-group">' +
                '<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Çəki</label>' +
                '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                '<input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" class="form-control" readonly>' +
                '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">'+
                    '<input type="submit" value="Əlavə et">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
            })
            $('#divFileInput').html(html);
        })
```

Now I want to fill these texboxes with values from database, but I faced with problem. I realize that I need to use AJAX, because PHP is a server side language.
I never use AJAX before, can I turn js script to ajax with some modificiations or I need to code again, how it should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using JQuery so you won't need any modifications. It looks like you need to fetch data from db to your script. You can check W3SCHOOLS [example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) but it is not secure to fetch db data to your script. You should use PHP for these purposes if you are using JQuery with PHP. Hope your question is answered...

Comment: You are right, the problem is in my fetching  code.Thank you for saving my time.